# Dipole moment dilemmas

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dipole-moment

Dipole moment for a couple of charges, say q and -q, separated by a distance 'd' is given by 'qd'

But what is for dissimilar magnitudes,say (q and 2q) or (q and -2q)?

And are dipole moment defined only for static charges or are they defined for moving/accelarated charges too..?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment

Comment: Non symmetrical dipole is a symmetrical dipole plus a point charge on one of the ends.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Let me add [this link](http://www.chem.ox.ac.uk/teaching/Physics%20for%20CHemists/Electricity/Dipoles.html). There you will find the general case for several different charges which can be globally non neutral. As @Asphir Dom said, the result is in fact the sum of a dipole and a point charge.

Answer (score 1):

Dipole antennae have moving (AC) charges.  And there is no reason the dipole has to be symmetric (equal charges).  You can work out the math for generic charge separation.  In general you have a multipole expansion:  monopole, dipole, quadrupole etc.